# Can I check if value was changed in prePersist()?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to automatically set one of the entity fields if it was not manually set. Is there a way to check this? The fields has a default value, so I can not simply compare the value. I was wondering if doctrine maintains whether or not value is changed and if I can access that information.

Also, Is prePersist in Doctrine 2 equivalent of preInsert in Doctrine 1? How can I make sure I only run code on create statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `prePersist` event ([docs about prePersist](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#prepersist)) is triggered when you call `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#persist` on an entity.
If you need to check for changes to an entity, I suggest you to check for the `onFlush` event ([docs about onFlush](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#onflush)). There you can obtain any changes you have applied to the entity using the `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork` API. Changes tracking on an entity happens after calling `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#persist`